# How to insert source code into my database and then echo it inside a value

Tags: php, sql, database

I got a WYSIWYG editor which works fine when typing myself, but if I copy paste from lets say a website, source code is copied with it, which I want to allow except at the moment this breaks my code.

Inside an input field I echo data so I can edit it and save to my database.

Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="'.$getversion['content'].'">
```

This works fine like I said when typing myself.

But if I for example copy some lorem ipsum text from a website, it copies style with it (font size, color etc).

This is saved like this:

```
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis libero erat, tincidunt id placerat vel, vehicula at mauris. Morbi nibh sapien, lacinia ultricies urna dapibus, placerat suscipit risus. Maecenas vulputate, ante at blandit aliquam, ante arcu sollicitudin diam, vitae commodo metus mi nec purus. Nullam a cursus justo, eget venenatis dolor. Etiam condimentum a lectus nec volutpat. Ut sodales vestibulum urna, sed eleifend est. Praesent diam nisl, fermentum a orci ac, viverra efficitur dui. Nam eget nulla ante. Suspendisse feugiat tortor non egestas sodales. Morbi id vestibulum nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">Mauris placerat rhoncus metus eu accumsan. Nulla porta tempor tincidunt. Aliquam commodo massa ac ullamcorper ullamcorper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras at ante consectetur, dictum metus auctor, viverra lectus. Mauris tincidunt libero nunc, eu mattis quam rhoncus in. Curabitur ut purus diam. Maecenas posuere elit eget consectetur consequat. Quisque vulputate a magna ac finibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ligula nisi, faucibus sed sodales eu, bibendum eu est. Integer blandit velit eget dui fermentum euismod. Maecenas finibus aliquet sem at auctor.</p>
```

As you can see it breaks because of the quotes:

[image]

What can I do about that?

I read I have to use real_escape_string again (I already use it on save) when echoing it but that does not fix it.

I should also mention I post it with ajax.

Comment: `real_escape` is for escaping characters special to SQL (also unrelated but prepared statements, with parameterized queries are what you should be using for the DB interaction). Use `htmlspecialchars` for outputting to the browser, also look at the constants for that function.

Answer (score -1):

When you are saving to the db, do this...

```
htmlentities($str);
```

when echoing out from the db do this...

```
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Comment: `When you are saving to the db` No, do not do that. That opens SQL injections. Your entity decode also opens XSS injections.